# 'Could not get reply from fzputtygen' error when adding private key to FileZilla

Tags: digital-ocean, openssh, filezilla

I'm trying to access a DigitalOcean droplet through FileZilla. I created a keypair using 'ssh-keygen' and provided DigitalOcean with the public key. When I open FileZilla -> Edit -> Settings -> SFTP, I click 'Add key file...' and select my private key (starting '-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----'). I then get a popup telling me the format isn't supported and asks me if i'd like to convert the file, to which I say yes and enter the password for the file which validates. I provide a new filename in the same directory and click save, which give me the 'Could not get reply from fzputtgen' error message.

I've tried re-downloading and installing FileZilla with no success but really have no idea where to go as the error is so vague. Hopefully somebody here has experience with this issue and can shed some light as to how I might go about fixing it. I'm sure I could create a keypair using PuTTY and skip this step, but it would be nice to have an explanation for why this is failing.

Comment: Did you generate an ed25519 key or RSA?
Edit: I am having this same issue. I initially tried with an ed25519 key, and retried with an RSA key but with same result.

Comment: Tried with an RSA key, as expected it worked first time after generating a PuTTY key pair instead. Didn't get any further using the openSSH keypair unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems 3.55 has the issue but works OK on 3.56.2.

Please refer to answer dated 27 Sep 2021 here: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=54091

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Incase the link dies - it's a known bug on V3.55 and the developer patched it in V3.56.2, no more information required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error "Could not get reply from fzputtygen" while import RSA key generated using ssh-keygen is a new bug in Mac computers, as reported at https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/12494#no1.

For this specific issue, keep track (at above url) until this still open case gets solved.